# Can a Canon T3 DSLR be used with my TAMRON AF TELE-MACRO 90-300mm lens?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, canon, old-lenses, tamron

Can a Canon T3 DSLR be used with my Tamron AF tele-macro 90-300mm lens?

I am trying to find a lower cost new camera (less than $500) to use with this lens that I previously used with a film camera.

1) Can the Canon T3 be used with this lens? and/or
2) Does anyone have another camera recommendation within this price range to use with this lens?

Comment: It depends what mount the lens is. Tamron makes lenses for multiple mounts, such as Nikon, Canon, Pentax, etc. What type of camera did you originally buy the lens for?

Comment: It's being used with a Minolta right now.

Comment: See [Can I use old Minolta AF lenses on my new Canon 550d?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/22857/can-i-use-old-minolta-af-lenses-on-my-new-canon-550d)

Comment: What sort of Minolta? Manual focus or autofocus? Is it native to that mount, or is it one of the old Tamron Adaptall/Adaptall II lenses? If it's an Adaptall II, you can remove the Minolta adapter, install a Canon adapter, and use it -- though they're long-discontinued, so finding the Canon adapter may not be easy. Also note that you'll have to operate it purely manually on the Canon body (manual focus, manual aperture, probably stop-down metering).

Comment: If your old camera was from [Minolta Alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minolta_AF) line, the same lens mount is used in current Sony Alpha line, so looking at Sony's lineup would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this lens, with a few trade offs.
1. You will have to buy a lens mount adapter. Try searching the mount it is in "to canon ef" on amazon.
2. Neither autofocus, nor auto exposure will work for this lens. This is because the adapter won't have electrical contacts. Depending on the lens, it may be possible to find an adapter with the contacts, but it will probably cost about ten times as much. 
Despite these trade offs, using an old lens is great! I use an old 50mm with my canon, and using manual focus forces me to be more creative. You also save a lot of money, by not having to buy a new lens.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any third party lens with your Canon camera, it just needs to have the **Canon Mount** This information will be visible somewhere on the packaging, you can also usually filter for this when shopping online.